# NeoVim-Lua-nvim-lspconfig-ccls: NO IntelliSense, Code Snippets, or Description popup, for C++

Tags: c++, lua, autocomplete, intellisense, nvim-lspconfig

**1. Using MacOS Catalina: Setting up NVIM-LUA-nvim-lspconfig-ccls, for lua and C++:**

**2. Build ccls: Following: https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls/wiki/Build**

```
$ brew install ccls
```

***Note**: I am NOT clear about additional instruction by mask ray, for brew installation of ccls*

**2. compile_commands.json:**

```
[{
  "directory": "/Users/pt/Documents/Code/C++/sample",
  "command": "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++17 -g -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.15 -o CMakeFiles/sample.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/pt/Documents/Code/C++/sample/main.cpp",
  "file": "/Users/pt/Documents/Code/C++/sample/main.cpp"
}]
```

**3. language_servers.lua:**

```
local servers = { 'ccls', 'sumneko_lua'  }
for _, lsp in pairs(servers) do
  lspconfig[lsp].setup {
    capabilities = capabilities,
  }
end

require('lspconfig')['ccls'].setup{
    on_attach = on_attach,
    flags = lsp_flags,
 }
```

**ISSUES:**

2. For C++, Simple Completions and Flags are there.
   BUT, ***there is NO IntelliSense, Code Snippets, or Description popup***.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have autocompletion, you must install a additional plugin as stated [here](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/wiki/Autocompletion).
Note, that for example `coq` has additionaly snippets [buildin](https://github.com/ray-x/lsp_signature.nvim).

To get a description popup (i guess about the current function for example), you can use another plugin like [`lsp_signature`](https://github.com/ray-x/lsp_signature.nvim).

Comment: Thank you @Mime (1) I already have nvim-lspconfig. (2) Now, I set it up with clangd. It works out of the box. It seems, it was developed by Clang-LLVM team. (3) As you advised, trying to set up lsp_signature, but it is not working... Any idea?